# How do I decode repeating unsigned MSB and LSB 8-bit words?

Tags: c++, c, embedded

I'm writing a module that accepts some data from a spectrometer via a serial port and needs to decode it. The spectral data is encoded as 512-bytes in repeating unsigned MSB and LSB 8-bit words according to the manual. How would I decode this in C/C++?

> 23 – 534 encoded as 512-bytes in repeating unsigned MSB and LSB 8-bit words
>   [MSB]*256 + [LSB].

That's a snippet from the manual.

Okay, I'd like to add in **another portion** to this question. According to a comment below, this is in big-endian. Now, what I'm confused about it is that if it indeed is in big-endian, wouldn't conversion to little-endian be as simple as reversing the order of all the bytes? And if that is the case, then the output to that would essentially be something like... LSB5, MSB5, LSB4, MSB4, LSB3, MSB3, LSB2, MSB2, LSB1, MSB1 and so on, which could then be converted to 16-bit words. What is it that I'm going wrong with here?

Also, if this is indeed big-endian, aren't there any native (even platform-specific if necessary, but faster) methods to handle the conversion?

Comment: What do you mean by "repeating MSB and LSB words"?

Comment: @H2CO3 The is a stream of bytes, like this: '[MSB1][LSB1][MSB2][LSB2][MSB3][LSB3]…'. Two bytes must be assembled into a word: '[WRD1][WRD2][WRD3]….'

Comment: Isn't this format precisely 16-bit unsigned big-endian?

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist I'm really confused at this point. Is this indeed Big-endian? And if yes, shouldn't there be a native conversion function maybe? Which, if I may speculate, would speed up things.

Comment: I don't quite understand the format of the data as you explained it. Am I right in saying that from bytes 23 to 534 of a _frame_ there are 256 sixteen-bit-wide ( = 2 byte) _samples_? If so, then there are only two ways the two bytes of each sample could be arranged in. Either the LSB comes first in the byte stream, or the MSB does. The former case is _little-endian_ and the latter case is _big-endian_. So far I've understood the MSB comes first, so that would make the samples big-endian. To decode them on little-endian x86 machines, you would have to byteswap _individually_ all 256 samples.

Comment: As for "native" functions, if you're on GCC you may use the built-in function `uint16_t __builtin_bswap16 (uint16_t x)`, for which no includes are needed, and if you're using Visual Studio you may use `unsigned short _byteswap_ushort(unsigned short val)`, provided you `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist You are absolutely right in your understanding of the format. Am I correct in further inferring from your explanation that, in case each sample was (say) 32 bit-wide, I could switch its endianness by means of swapping the order of all four bytes?

Comment: @Siddharth Absolutely! And you'd do that with the uint32_t versions of those functions.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist So, the chosen answer below is just a platform independent implementation of the same, I take it. Performance considerations taken into account, which would be faster? The platform independent versions below or the "native" functions? I understand that naturally the former would ensure portability, but what if that consideration was put aside for a second?

Comment: For something so simple as byteswapping any decent compiler can probably detect shifts-and-OR implementations and substitute in the BSWAP instruction. Using those builtins merely makes it clearer to the reader and compiler, which might optimize better as a result.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Okay, one last question. I know this may seem dumb, but I'm still a little confused about endianness. I thought big-endian would imply that the samples would be in the reverse order as that of little-endian. Is endianness always sample specific like in this case? Simply put, does it control the order of the samples as well, or just of the bytes within each individual sample?

Comment: Endianness controls only the order of the _bytes_ within a _sample_, not the order of the _samples_ within the _frame_. Thus a little-endian 16-bit stream resembles `[LSB0][MSB0] [LSB1][MSB1] [LSB2][MSB2] [LSB3][MSB3] [LSB4][MSB4]...` while a big-endian 16-bit stream resembles `[MSB0][LSB0] [MSB1][LSB1] [MSB2][LSB2] [MSB3][LSB3] [MSB4][LSB4]...`

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist And when you say stream, can that be generalized to the various types including file, serial, network and so on? Meaning, if I take a binary file saved on a system of the ARM7 architecture (I believe, big-endian) and access it on an Intel Core i5 for instance (little-endian architecture), all I need to do is swap the bytes of the individual samples within the stream? And the sample size, in this case would be dictated by the particular file format, in question?

Comment: Essentially, yes. If you read a field of a struct written by a machine with a different endianness, you byteswap it. If you read an array by such a machine, you byte-swap all the individual elements. Your format specifies the size of the samples, and both machines must agree on that at least; But formats also usually specify an endianness too, either little or big, and the "losing" machine must do byte-swaps. _(Quick dispute: ARM processors are bi-endian usually defaulting to little-endian. It's PowerPC that's more commonly thought of as big-endian)_.

Comment: Superb! Thank you so much for the clear and precise explanation! (I see! Any ideas on switching a processor's endianness, by means of software?)

Comment: That's something done at firmware and OS level, and changing the processor's endianness midstride is probably practically impossible. All of ARM, x86 and PowerPC have fast byteswap instructions – they are probably entirely enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm an over-optimizer sometimes, so even though Fiddling Bits has provided a perfectly adequate solution, it has unneeded divides and unneeded branches.  So I'll serve up a redundant answer here.

```
uint8_t byteArray[512];
uint16_t wordArray[256], word, byteIdx, wordIdx;

for (byteIdx=0, wordIdx=0; byteIdx < 511; )
{
    word = byteArray[byteIdx++] << 8;
    wordArray[wordIdx++] = word | byteArray[byteIdx++]
}
```

The key concept is to shift the MSB byte up 8 bits (x<<8 is equivalent to x*256) then or/add it to the LSB to form the 16-bit word.  The rest is all index management.

Comment: Well played! I always appreciate optimization.

Answer (score 4):

You'd need to store the MSB and LSB into a single word.  For example:

```
uint8_t msb, lsb;
uint16_t word;

word = (msb << 8) | lsb;
```

A loop of this would look something like this:

```
uint8_t byteArray[512];
uint16_t wordArray[256], byteArrIdx;

for(byteArrIdx = 0; byteArrIdx < 512; byteArrIdx++)
{
    if((byte % 2) == 0)
        wordArray[(byteArrIdx / 2)] = byteArray[byteArrIdx] << 8;
    else
        wordArray[(byteArrIdx / 2)] |= byteArray[byteArrIdx];
}
```

Note:

The output of `msb << 8` and `msb * 256` is identical.  I prefer using bit shifting because your intentions are more clear to the reader.

Comment: You've earned your name for today. But why didn't you use `byte & 1` instead of `byte % 2`? P.S. `byte` needs to be something bigger than `uint8_t` in your code sample.

Comment: @MarkRansom Are you sure a bigger type is necessary?  The OP describes the data as *unsigned MSB and LSB 8-bit words*.

Comment: 512 is much greater than 255, the `for` loop will never terminate.

Comment: @MarkRansom Why would he use the bitwise and when he wants to test for every n-th byte? The modulo operator is better conceptually.

Comment: You're using `byte` as an index into an array. Perhaps it would have been better to choose a different name.

Comment: @H2CO3, I wasn't being particularly serious. `byte & 1` and `byte % 2` are functionally equivalent, but the first uses bit fiddling. For that matter `byte / 2` could have been replaced with `byte >> 1` too.

Comment: @MarkRansom Ugh... I didn't notice you were being sarcastic (nor did I get the joke about the name for the first try), sorry!

Comment: @MarkRansom You deserve the `Bit Fiddling` title more than I.

Comment: @H2CO3: I'd argue that & 1 is preferable, if just slightly, since the code is intrinsically bit-fiddly and it works for negative indices. I've managed to get bitten by that division-towards-zero discontinuity a rather unfortunate number of times :(

Comment: Consider `if((byteArrIdx % 2) == 0)` instead of `if((byte % 2) == 0)`.

Comment: The `if` statement can be removed with a separate indices for the byte and word arrays.